# Constraints inside Scroll View

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, autolayout, scrollview

I'm working on application for iOS. Trying to use Autolayout with **Scroll View**.
But there is some problem. I have **View** -> **Scroll View** -> **Content View** hierarchy. I pinned (top, bottom, left, right) of the **Scroll View** to the **Main View**, and also pinned **Content View** to **Scroll View**.
Then i've added imageView on the top of the screen and text label below, to the **Content View**. Added them constraints including **vertical spacing** (8pt) from image to label. In Preview everything looks ok and label placed right below image, however when i'm running the app on iOS Simulator, my label places right in the middle of image. Please, any help?

Comment: Could you post a screenshot of InterfaceBuilder?  Are there any orange tinted lines?

Comment: Yes, here is screenshot http://prntscr.com/7z64fu. All constraints seems ok

Comment: And here is how it looks on iOS Simulator http://prntscr.com/7z656w

Comment: Maybe a wrong content scaling mode of the image? Or: is there any connection from the label to the bottom (maybe via the text view)? then i would remove the constraint to the bottom of the view.

Comment: Yeah, this was because my image has **Aspect Fill** mode. So i added **ClipsToBounds - true** and now it seems works fine. Thanks!

Comment: Perfect. I put this into an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We found an answer in the comments: it was due to a wrong content scaling mode of the image. It needed to be `ClipToBounds`.